# Google Analytics gtag.js ready callback

Tags: analytics, google-analytics-api, gtag.js

I try to update my Google Analytics implementation from analytics.js to the new gtag.js.

In the old implementation I am using the [ready callback](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/command-queue-reference#ready-callback) function.

```
ga(function() {
    console.log('Google analytics is ready'); 
});
```

How can I implement a ready callback in the new gtag.js? I can't find any information in Google's documentation.

Comment: Can you expand on what you are trying to do? What do you use the callback for exactly?

Answer (score 12):

The command `event` supports the parameter `event_callback`, a function called when processing has completed. So, compared to the old `analytics.js`, you need to send an event to trigger the callback.

For example, you can use the [`page_view`](https://developers.google.com/gtagjs/reference/event#page_view) event; however, to avoid duplicates, you must disable the automatic `page_view` event by setting `send_page_view` to `false`.

```
gtag('config', GA_TRACKING_ID, {
  'send_page_view': false
});
gtag('event', 'page_view', {
  'event_callback': function() {
    console.log('Google Analytics is ready'); 
  }
});
```

Comment: This is a great answer, the only thing that's missing is a reference to the documentation. Here: https://developers.google.com/gtagjs/reference/event

Comment: Couldn't we just set like this to get the ready callback?


`gtag('config', GA_TRACKING_ID, { event_callback: alert('Ready'), })`

Comment: Actually `'event_callback'` property doesn't seem to be in the docs

Comment: Just to note, ```gtag('config', GA_TRACKING_ID, { event_callback: alert('Ready'), })``` **doesn't** work because the ```config``` command *doesn't* call the ```event_callback``` - only the ```event``` command does that - see https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/gtagjs/reference/parameters "event_callback | function | function() { form.submit(); } | JavaScript callback function called when processing of an **event** command has completed.```...

Comment: Docs for `event_ballback` are here: https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/gtagjs/reference/parameters An important note: `event_ballback` is being fired before the actual server request is completed. So it can not be used as a reliable source of information about wether event was successfully submitted to GA servers or not.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler (but probably less reliable) solution is to use the `onload` attribute of the `<script>` tag:

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=GA_TRACKING_ID"
  onload="console.log('Google analytics is ready');">
</script>
```