# How to wait client-side for pageview event in Google Analytics 4

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

**Background**: I've (very) recently started using Google Analytics 4 for a small community website to track how many times a QR Code is scanned on a physical advertising flier we're going to be distributing.

The url in the QR Code basically points to a page that loads `gtag.js` which sends a `pageview` event with the `utm_` codes from the querystring in the url, and then some client-side javascript redirects the user to a 3rd party ticket sales site that doesn't support Google Analytics.

This all seems to works with the following page content:

```html
    <!-- Google tag (gtag.js) -->
    <script src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=<my_measurement_id>"></script>
    <script>
        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        function gtag() { dataLayer.push(arguments); }
        gtag('js', new Date());
        gtag('config', '<my_measurement_id>');
    </script>
    <script>
        window.addEventListener("load", function () {
            window.location = "<my_redirect_url>"
        }, false);
    </script>
```

I see `pageview` events in the **Debug View** page in the Google Analytics portal and the page redirects to the correct location, but I've arrived at this through trial, error and no small amount of stumbling luck, so what I'd like to understand is whether this is a **reliable** way to wait for the `pageview` event to be sent before the client-side redirect happens, or whether it just **happens** to work right now on my machine while I'm testing it, but may break when released into the wild...

And if the latter, is there a "correct" way to delay running some javascript until the `pageview` event has been sent?

For example, can client-side script "observe" events that are sent, or is there a callback that can be registered for when the `pageview` event has been sent?

(This may also be an XY Problem in that I've started down this route and gotten it sort-of working - if there's a better / simpler way to ensure a redirect only happens *after* the `pageview` event is sent I'd be happy to hear that as well...)

Comment: There is a similar question with yours. The keyword is `event_callback`
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47695531/google-analytics-gtag-js-ready-callback

Comment: @darrelltw - I've been gradually refining my search terms and just come across that question myself :-). I'll need to test it, but the answer looks pretty much like it will work. Does that make this a duplicate question, or a different question that just has the same answer?

Comment: I am not sure about the duplicate problem but glad you found it. Maybe someone will search the term similar with yours then find the solution as well in the future.

Answer (score 0):

@darrellt found the answer for me in another similar but slightly different question - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/52774905/3156906 (pasting link here as an answer in case comments get cleaned up).